# How to cast data in timestamp column to integer value in SQL query on postgres database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to read data from GP and ingest to HDFS using Spark. I need an integer column to partition the data which I read from the GP table. 
The problem here is I don't have a primary column or any column that has unique values. In this scenario, column that I can rely on the most is the timestamp column where I can convert it to Integer/Long .

The data in timestamp column is present in the format:

```
select max(last_updated_timestamp) from schema.tablename => 2018-12-13 13:29:55
```

Could anyone let me know how can I cast the timestamp column including its milliseconds and produce an EPOCH value from it which I can use it in my spark code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extract(epoch from last_updated_timestamp)`.

Comment: Ok. Just asking, I am getting the values with decimal numbers: 1550551127.310969. Is it possible to get it as 1550551127310969 ?

Comment: I think its ok for your needs just to multiply by 1000000: extract(epoch from last_updated_timestamp)*1000000 or even larger number if you get more digits after the decimal point.